# MacOS Appkit: how to detect non standard mouse button clicks?

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, mac-catalyst

I know we can detect mouse down/up but is there a way to detect mouse clicks of non-standard buttons? Like my razor mouse has side buttons for going back / forward. Can those be detected?

Comment: I think they are generally mapped to keys; the mouse pretends that it is a keyboard, and the non-standard buttons are keys like left-arrow / right-arrow, etc.

Comment: @bhaller you helped in the right direction. I ended up on this: https://sensible-side-buttons.archagon.net which explains how he achieved the detection of side buttons. He detected using `swipeWithEvent`. Apparently that event is called for mouse side button events. Now I need to figure out why it's being called twice for some reason.

Comment: Nvm, I figured out why it was calling it twice. I was able to add `event.phase == .began` as a condition. Seems like it gets called at start of the fake swipe gesture and at the end.